# What is difference between string[] & [string,string,string]

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, d3.js

I have a requirement for d3 locale.

```
timeFormatDefaultLocale({
  "dateTime": "%A, der %e. %B %Y, %X",
  "date": "%d.%m.%Y",
  "time": "%H:%M:%S",
  "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
  "days": ["Sonntag", "Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag"],
  "shortDays": ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"],
  "months": ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"],
  "shortMonths": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mrz", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez"]
})
```

So if I do following change:

```
"shortDays": moment.weekdaysShort(),
```

I am getting this error:

```
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '[string, string, string, string, string, string, string]'.
      Property '0' is missing in type 'string[]'.
```

Any help. why this error is coming?

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tuple type (`[string, string, ...]`) has a fixed length, whereas `string[]` can have any length. So in other words: It expects seven weekday strings, but you are passing an array of strings with unknown length (the type system does not know that it's length is 7).

As with every type error you can circumvent the type checking with `any`:

```
 moment.weekdaysShort() as any
```